# Custom service account for App Engine service

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have multiple micro-services running on our project's GCP (Google Cloud Platform) App Engine.  In our case, it would be preferable to minimize permissions on a per-service basis.  Currently, we keep all the credential files in Keybase, keeping secrets sectioned off by team membership.  So if I am working on one App Engine service, I can't see the secrets for another team's app engine service.
What we have been doing for other secrets, e.g. config files with passwords and secret tokes, we give the app engine service account kms decryption privileges and simply pull an encrypted copy of the config file from firestore and decrypt it.  But we don't want to use the default app engine service account everywhere, because different teams using the same service accounts would have access to everyone's secrets.  So we want to move to a service account on a per-service basis for each app engine service in development.

From what I can tell in the Google documentation, they want to you to upload up the credential file(s) when we deploy the app, which works, however, from the cloud console, it appears difficult to lock down who can look at the the files deployed to the service, and anyone with access could simply copy/paste all the credentials.

If you have the config in a dictionary, you do something like this:

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import kms_v1
d = {'type': 'service_account',
     'project_id': 'my-awesome-project',
     'private_key_id': '074139282fe9834ac23401',
     'private_key': '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----\n supersecretkeythatnobodyknows==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
     'client_email': 'my-cool-address@my-awesome-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
     'client_id': '1234567890',
     'auth_uri': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
     'token_uri': 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
     'auth_provider_x509_cert_url': 
     'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
     'client_x509_cert_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/my-cool-addres%40my-awesome-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'}

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(d)
kms_client = kms_v1.KeyManagementServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
```

This works, but how do we get the dictionary "d" into the program without it showing up in the code and having accessible by a broad range of people?

Answer (score 0):

If each service in your AppEngine environment have to have their own identity, it's not possible with AppEngine. Newer service like Cloud Function or Cloud run can do this, but the very old service (for cloud era) AppEngine (more than 10 years old) can't.

You have a service account for all AppEngine service. You can use it to decrypt others services account key file, per service and use them in the appropriate service, but the root authorization stay the default App Engine service account, and thereby all services/all teams can have access to it (and to all the encrypted service account key files).

Maybe the solution is to redesign the application and to have a project per team?

Answer (score 0):

What guillaume blaquiere said in his answer is correct and I agree with his idea of having a project per team, also. You cannot make a different service account for each of your App Engine's services.

Although what you want to achieve may be somehow possible in the App Engine flexible. OK, so you cannot find a way to only allow some team for some service and other team for the other. What you can do ( but I do not think that you want that and I would not recommend either ) is blocking certain IPs, by [controlling your access with Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/creating-firewalls). You can create your own firewall rules and allow request from one place and do not from another place.

This is just a trick that may or may not work for you. The real advice is that if you really want to implement the system you have described clean and correctly with more service accounts you should consider migrating to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/).